# Xamarin - как передать значение идентификатора из базы данных в выпадающий список?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

Здравствуйте. В приложении имеются следующие две таблицы, которые заполняются данными:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле "Store" в приложении заполняется через выпадающий список Picker. Для этого используется класс PurchasePage. В нем определение индекса текущего элемента в выпадающем списке производится путем поиска элемента в массиве по имени:

```
public PurchasePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Заполняем выпадающий список
        var StoreArray = App.database.GetStores().ToArray();
        var a = new List<string>();
        foreach (var StoreName in StoreArray)
        {
            Picker.Items.Add(StoreName.store_name);
        }

        //Определяем текущий элемент в выпадающем списке
        var PurchaseArray = App.database.GetPurchases().ToArray();
        foreach (var Purchase in PurchaseArray)
        {
            //GetStore производит выборку по id
            var Store = App.database.GetStore(Purchase.store_id);
            var curArr = Picker.Items.IndexOf(Store.store_name);
            if(curArr != -1) Picker.SelectedIndex = curArr;
        }
    }
```

Далее для сохранения данных определяется имя текущего выбранного элемента:

```
var selectedStore = Picker.Items[Picker.SelectedIndex];
```

Переменная selectedStore передается в метод SavePurchase, который сохраняет данные в таблицу. В этом методе производится выборка идентификатора по имени:

```
        public int SavePurchase(Purchase item, string store)
    {
        var store_id =  database.Query<Store>("Select store_id from Store where store_name=\""+ store + "\"");
        item.store_id = store_id[0].store_id;
        if (item.purchase_id != 0)
        {
            database.Update(item);
            return item.purchase_id;
        }
        else
        {
            return database.Insert(item);
        }
    }
```

Как передать значение идентификатора сразу в выпадающий список, чтобы каждый раз не приходилось искать его значение по имени элемента?